# confused about wp_list_pages() function - how to display selected top pages with all their subpages

Tags: navigation, pages, list, menus, include

I'm a bit confused about `wp_list_pages()` function.

Lets say I have 3 top level pages (with no parent) and each of them have some sub-pages:

- page 1 [sub-pages: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3];
- page 2 [sub-pages: 2.1, 2.2, 2.3];
- page 3 [sub-pages: 3.1, 3.2]

What I'm trying to do is to display top level pages 2 and 3 with all their subpages:

```
wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=0&title_li=&include=2,3' );
```

I have also tried so specify the depth as depth=2:

```
wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=2&title_li=&include=2,3' );
```

However, the top level pages 2 and 3 are displayed with no subpages. I'm not sure if I understood the function description correctly.

How do I achive such functionality when sub-pages can be added/deleted at any time.

Many thanks,
Dasha

Comment: When you use `include` you're explicitly setting which pages to return in the result, so you're basically limiting the result to those two pages.

Comment: @t31os Oh I see. Is there some smart way to do what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: `exclude_tree`? eg: `wp_list_pages( 'exclude_tree=N&yourotherargs=something' )` where N would be an ID of the top level page to exclude.

Comment: @t31os thanks for the tip. I went for `include` option and collecting all the pages `ids` to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `@Bainternet` for pointing me to the `exclude_tree`, although I ended up using a bit different code.

It was important to be able to add top-level pages that don't have to appear in the menu (for example for [Improved Include Page Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/improved-include-page). Using the `exclude_tree` I would need to update the code every time a new top-level page is added.

Instead, I have an array of all top-level pages that need to appear in the menu. I then collect all their desendant pages and use `wp_list_pages` to display only secelted pages.

Here is the code:

```
<?php //main nav: use wp_list_pages to display cirtain parents pages and all thier descendant pages
$parents = array(2,3);
$children = array();
foreach($parents as $parent) {
    $child_pages = get_pages( "child_of=$parent" );
    if($child_pages){
        foreach($child_pages as $child_page){
            $children[] = $child_page->ID;
        }
    }
}
//merge $parents and $children
$menu_pages = array_merge((array)$parents, (array)$children);
$menu_pages_str = implode(",", $menu_pages); 
?>

<ul id="main-nav">
    <?php wp_list_pages( "sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&include=$menu_pages_str" ); ?>
</ul>
```

Also, have a look at the Codex [List parent Page and all descendant Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages#List_parent_Page_and_all_descendant_Pages) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `include` parameter of wp_list_pages you are basically telling it to only include these certain Pages in the list.

you should use `exclude_tree` instead, when using this parameter it will exclude a parent and all of that parent's child Pages.

so something like:

```
$top_pages_to_exclude = '1'; // the top page to be excluded ID, you can specify more then one '1,2,23'

$args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'depth' => 2,
    'title_li' => '',
    'exclude_tree' => $top_pages_to_exclude
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that! It pointed me in the right direction. It's very important to be able to create new top level pages, for example for the [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/improved-include-page] (Improved Include Page Plugin). In the case of exclude_tree I would need to update it every time a new top level page is added. So I went for a bit different solution: go through all the menu pages and collect their descendants. Please see my answer for code.